# Minimal polynimomial and operator

Tags: linear-algebra

If given a (monic) polynomial $p$ it is possible to find an operator $T$ so that $p$ is its minimal polynomial. I can do it for easy polynomials (like $x^2$) with trying. I was wondering: is there a method to apply to find such operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jared notes, you can take the companion matrix of the polynomial which will in fact have both minimal and characteristic polynomial equal to $p$.

More generally, given polynomials $p$ and $q$ in which $p\mid q$ and every irreducible factor of $q$ appears in $p$, you can find an operator $T$ which has minimal polynomial $p$ and characteristic polynomial $q$. You can do this by considering the [Jordan Canonical Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of the operator and selecting the Jordan blocks accordingly.

**Edit:** In response to OP's comments.

You must have two $0$s appear on the diagonal in the same block for the minimal polynomial to be $x^2$. This means that the size of the largest block is size $2$.

The last diagonal entry also has to be zero since all the eigenvalues of the operator must be zero. All in all, you have something of the form
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Note that this operator is uniquely determined (up to similarity).

Comment: If I may, I think that the most appropriate form to speak about matrix "characteristic" polynomials (characteristic in the sense of the following) is the Frobenius normal form http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form

Comment: How to use Jordan form to find the matrix? I tried with $x^2$ and tried diagonal entries $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ and second diagonal above with all equal $1$. It did not work. What is the algorithm how to determine Jordan blocks?

Comment: @blue Please see the edit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for edit! Why do I have to have two $0$s on the diagonal in the same block? I don't understand how you deduce the size of the largest block. I understand it is one block for every distinct eigen value. Then there would only be one block?

Comment: I understand it, I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) that the multiplicity of the $\lambda$ is the number of Jordan blocks corresponding to it. Then for $x^2$ it means two Jordan blocks for $0$. But I still don't understand how to find the companion matrix if the degree of the polynomial is smaller than dimension of the space. Please, can you help me with that also?

Comment: @blue The companion matrix always has minimal polynomial equal to characteristic polynomial. That means the companion matrix must have size equal to the degree of the polynomial. Simply put, there does not exist a $3\times 3$ companion matrix for $x^2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand it: in the edit why can it not be two blocks for $0$? The Wikipedia states that the algebraic multiplicity is equal to the sum of the sizes of the blocks. You write both zeros are in the same block. Why is it the case? Thank you.

Comment: @blue The matrix has only $0$ as an eigenvalue and there are three scenarios for the Jordan form of the matrix. First case scenario is that there are $3$ blocks of size $1$. This is just the zero matrix. This can't be the case because we know the minimal polynomial is $x^2$. The second case is for there to be one block of size $3$. But this isn't the case either since that gives a matrix with minimal polynomial $x^3$. The only remaining case is for there to be one block of size $2$ and one block of size $1$ which is what I wrote down.

Comment: More generally, suppose that your minimal polynomial is given by $$p(x) = (x-\lambda_1)^{m_1}\cdot(x-\lambda_2)^{m_2}\cdots(x-\lambda_k)^{m_k}$$ Then the eigenvalues of your matrix are the roots of the polynomial $\{\lambda_1,\ \lambda_2,\ \cdots,\ \lambda_k\}$ and the largest Jordan block for each each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ will be the corresponding exponent $m_i$. In your case your minimal polynomial is $x^2$, so $0$ is your only eigenvalue and its exponent is $2$. That means the largest $0$-block in your Jordan form will be of size $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Great question.  The concept you're looking for here is the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), $C(p)$, of a monic polynomial $p$.

Comment: How to compute the companion matrix if the matrix size is different from space dimension? It did not work when I tried $x^2$ and $\mathbb C^3 \to \mathbb C^3$. Then $c_0 = c_1 =0$ and $n=2$?